# Center align section title, with font not bold

Tags: sectioning

I wish to mimic the alignment and font of this section heading (not necessarily with the leading character larger than the rest):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your preamble should do what you want:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\large\filcenter}{\thesection.}{1em}{\textsc}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the AMS article does this by default. And if you are mimicing some other document, that original document is probably an AMS article. Replace your `documentclass` with this:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
```

I put `reqno` so that your math equation number will be on the right side.